# Google one tap sign in behaves differently in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-one-tap

I recently implemented Google One Tap sign-in functionality in our website using PHP and JavaScript.
It seems to be functioning smoothly overall. However, during testing, I encountered an issue that I hope someone can assist me with.

**Observations:**

**In Chrome Browser:**
When I'm not logged into my Google account and visit our site, the Google One Tap sign-in prompt fails to appear.

**In Safari and Firefox Browsers:**
Contrastingly, when I'm not logged into my Google account and visit our site, the Google One Tap sign-in prompt displays.

Ofcourse, in all 3 browsers if I'm logged in to my Google account and visit our site, the Google one Tap sign-in prompt displays.

Is it typical for Chrome to behave differently compared to Safari and Firefox? Or should I revisit my JavaScript function?

Comment: What happens when you
a) Clear all cookies and caches or
b) go into incognito mode
The reason why I expect a change is due to [Exponential cooldowns](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/features#exponential_cooldown)

Comment: Do you get any error msg on chrome's dev console also if any extension that might be affecting the sign-in prompt

Answer (score 2):

After some research I found out that this is not a problem with your code but it is chromes functionality.
So you don't have to revisit your code base.

If you want it to appear even if you are not logged in on chrome you can set the `data-itp_support` attribute to true